# Conditional XSL for each loop within XSL for each

Tags: xml, xslt, db2

I have scenario here where I need to generate an xml with newnode1 using XSLT by reading an xml node1 which can be passed with 'n' number of times and node2 which can be passed as 'n' number of times also.
Here is how my xml looks like..

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Node>
    <Node_1>
       <Line>1</Line>
       <Text>First node1</Text>
       <Desc>Desc1</Desc>
       <Cust>Cust1</Cust>
    </Node_1>
    <Node_1>
       <Line>2</Line>
       <Text>First node2</Text>
       <Desc>Desc2</Desc>
       <Cust>Cust2</Cust>
    </Node_1>
    <Node_2>
       <Line>1</Line>
       <ReadInd>Y</ReadInd>
       <WriteInd>Y</WriteInd>
       <UpdateInd>Y</UpdateInd>
    </Node_2>
    <Node_2>
       <Line>2</Line>
       <ReadInd>N</ReadInd>
       <WriteInd>N</WriteInd>
       <UpdateInd>N</UpdateInd>
    </Node_2>
    </Node>
```

Below is the XSLT code that I have implemented for this, but I do see performance issue while running, it takes more time when my input XML Node_1 and Node_2 is repeated for more than 100 loops.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"   
xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">     
<xsl:template match = "/">   
<xsl:for-each select="Node/Node_1">
    <xsl:variable name="line" select="//Node_1/Line"/>
    <line><xsl:value-of select="Line"/></line>
    <text><xsl:value-of select="Text"/></text>
    <desc><xsl:value-of select="Desc"/></desc>
    <cust><xsl:value-of select="Cust"/></cust>
    <xsl:for-each select="/Node/Node_2">
        <xsl:if test="Line=$line">
            <readind><xsl:value-of select="ReadInd"/></readind>
            <writeind><xsl:value-of select="WriteInd"/></writeind>
            <updateind><xsl:value-of select="UpdateInd"/></updateind>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, I have used xsl:for each within another xsl:for each, and an if condition to check the line num each time when the xsl:for each executes.. Is there a simple logic to get my result, apart from what I tried.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem you have is how you define the `line` variable

```
<xsl:variable name="line" select="//Node_1/Line"/>
```

This selects all `Line` elements under all `Node_1` elements in your XML. This means when you do `<xsl:if test="Line=$line">`, this will actually return true regardless of what `Node_1` you are processing, thus you will output all `Node_2` elements.

You should define it like so

However, for efficient look up, consider using a key

```
<xsl:key name="node2" match="Node_2" use="Line" />
```

Then you can select the `Node_2` elements like so

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('node2', $line)">
```

Or even like this, as there is no need for a variable in this case as the current node is still `Node_1` at this point

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('node2', Line)">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="node2" match="Node_2" use="Line" />

<xsl:template match="/">   
    <xsl:for-each select="Node/Node_1">
        <node>
        <line><xsl:value-of select="Line"/></line>
        <text><xsl:value-of select="Text"/></text>
        <desc><xsl:value-of select="Desc"/></desc>
        <cust><xsl:value-of select="Cust"/></cust>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('node2', Line)">
            <subnode>
            <readind><xsl:value-of select="ReadInd"/></readind>
            <writeind><xsl:value-of select="WriteInd"/></writeind>
            <updateind><xsl:value-of select="UpdateInd"/></updateind>
            </subnode>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </node>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Note, I added the creation of `node` and `subnode` tags just to make it easier to see the correct `Node_2` elements were associated with each `Node_1`)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for highlighting the issue with the line variable.. i was wondering why it is giving incorrect results. This cleared my doubt..  Now I modified the logic exactly as you suggested using xsl:key function and it works as expected.. Another doubt, is if i have multiple conditions to check with like <xsl:if test="(Line=$line  and SubLine=$subline">.. does the xsl:key function help here too ?

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 you would have to do `<xsl:key name="node2" match="Node_2" use="Concat(Line, '|', SubLine)" />` and then to do use the key you would do `<xsl:if test="key('node2', concat($line, '|', $subline))">`